# Подскажите регулярку

Tags: php

В тексте встречаются такие наборы (может быть много) [10-4-391][10-4-392].. 
Как получить каждую цифру из набора в скобках ? Цифры могут быть разные
спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_match_all(/\[(\d+)\-(\d+)\-(\d+)\]/, $txt, $m)`

`$m` должно содержать то, что Вам надо

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('/\d+/' , $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: А цифры вне наборов тоже найдутся?

Comment: @br3t Конечно найдутся

Comment: Возможно, автора вопроса интересуют только цифры из наборов и не интересуют остальные цифры.

Comment: @br3t Можете поставить минус